# Why don't my datasets show up on line graph using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to display a line chart on a webpage using Chart.js that shows the number of downloads in the apple store and google play store for a specific client for the past 5 days. The data appears properly, but does not properly label the X axis with this:

```
var downloadsChartData = {
    labels: ["4 Days", "3 Days", "2 Days", "Yesterday", "Today"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Google Play",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 230, 115, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0, 230, 115, 1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(150, 75, 75, 1)",
        pointBorderWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 6,
        pointHoverRadius: 9,
        pointStyle: 'triangle',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 3
        }, {
            x: 4,
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 1
        }]
    }, {
        label: "iOS",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(26, 117, 255, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(26, 117, 225, 1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(150, 75, 75, 1)",
        pointBorderWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 6,
        pointHoverRadius: 9,
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 4
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: 4,
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 4
        }]
    }]
};

var downloadsChartOptions = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Downloads on Google Play and App Store',
        fontSize: 30
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                abelString: 'Date',
                fontSize: 20
            },
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Downloads',
                fontSize: 20
            }
        }]
    }
};

var downloadsChart = document.getElementById('downloadsChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(downloadsChart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: downloadsChartData,
    options: downloadsChartOptions
});
```

I tried to switch the `data` field to an array of values so that Chart.js would recognize the labels I defined in `downloadsChartData` to:

```
...
pointStyle: 'triangle',
data: [2, 0, 3, 1, 1]
}]
...
pointHoverRadius: 9,
data: [4, 2, 0, 1, 4]
}]
```

However, when I make this change, the chart not only doesn't correctly label the X axes, but also stops displaying the data on the line chart entirely.

Can someone please spot what I'm doing incorrectly? The documentation isn't too helpful in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear on this point, but for graphing non-numerical data (such as your case where the X axis represents a Date) you cannot set the X axis to have a linear scale.  In other words, if you set your axis with a linear scale, it will graph the numerical representation of the data (and therefore, not the label).

I removed `type: 'linear'` from your `downloadsChartOptions` and it solved the issue.:

```
var downloadsChartOptions = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Downloads on Google Play and App Store',
        fontSize: 30
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Date',
                fontSize: 20
            },
            //type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Downloads',
                fontSize: 20
            }
        }]
    }
};
```